# For loop gets interrupted without a reason

Tags: java, for-loop

I am making a 2048 clone, but it's refusing to merge blocks that aren't on the first row/column of interaction, after further investigation I found out that a for loop isn't doing it's job properly

Sample code for demonstration purposes:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class teste{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] gameBoard = new int[] {4,2,2,0} ;

    gameBoard = pushLeft(gameBoard);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(gameBoard));

  }


  public static int[] pushLeft(int[] gameBoard) {
    System.out.println("Pushing left...");
    // This one is the troublemaker
    for (int y = 1; y < 4; y++) {
      System.out.println("Y = " + y);
      boolean[] alreadyCombined = { false, false, false, false };
      if(gameBoard[y] != 0) {
        int value = gameBoard[y];
        int aux = y-1;
        while ( (aux >= 0) && (gameBoard[aux] == 0)) {
          aux--;
        }
        if (aux == -1) {
          gameBoard[y] = 0;
          gameBoard[0] = value;
        }
        else if (gameBoard[aux] != value && y-aux != 1) {
          gameBoard[y] = 0;
          gameBoard[aux+1] = value;
        }
        else if(gameBoard[aux] != value) {
          break;
        }
        else {
          if(alreadyCombined[aux]) {
            gameBoard[y] = 0;
            gameBoard[aux+1] = value;
          }
          else {
            gameBoard[y] = 0;
            gameBoard[aux] *= 2;
            alreadyCombined[aux] = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return gameBoard;
  }
```

This code returns this output:

```
Pushing left...
Y = 1
[4, 2, 2, 0]
```

As you can see, it's missing Y = 2 and Y = 3, and this makes so the 2 inner two's don't combine. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to need to use your debugger to find out why this is happening.

Comment: debug your code. break; can be reason for issue.

Comment: You could simply debug and found out, did you try to see what happen in this iteration?

Comment: This is a classic question that isn't meant for Stack Overflow. You can clearly solve this with a debugger, it offers no significance to future developers whatsoever and is pretty long relatively to the issue. Therefore I'm downvoting it, with an off-topic flag.

Comment: OP here: Thanks for everyone that answered my question! As for the debugger thing, I'm sorry I disappointed some of you, but I trully didn't know about the existence of this feature, I'll be more careful in the future

Answer (score 2):

Your code goes through

```
else if(gameBoard[aux] != value) {
          break;
        }
```

So the break force you to stop the loop because `value = 2` et and `gameBoard[aux] = 4`
You should try to print those values to see where is your problem

Answer (score 1):

in your code

```
 else if(gameBoard[aux] != value) {
              break;
            }
```

in first iteration `gabeBoard[aux] (4)` not equl to `value (2)`. So it is going through break.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Its not really what you asked for, but more what you wanted I think :-)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] g = new int[] {4,2,2,0} ;

    pushLeft(g);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(g));
    g = new int[] {0,0,2,2} ;
    pushLeft(g);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(g));
    g = new int[] {4,2,0,0} ;
    pushLeft(g);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(g));
    g = new int[] {0,0,0,0} ;
    pushLeft(g);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(g));
    g = new int[] {0,0,0,2} ;
    pushLeft(g);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(g));

}

private static void pushLeft(int[] g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
        // shift left
        for (int j = i+1; j < g.length; j++) {
            if (g[i] == 0 && g[j] > 0) {
                g[i] = g[j];
                g[j] = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        // combine left
        for (int j = i+1; j < g.length; j++) {
            if (g[i] > 0 && g[i] == g[j]) {
                g[i] *= 2;
                g[j] = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
[4, 4, 0, 0]
[4, 0, 0, 0]
[4, 2, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0, 0]
```